# JavaScript Pattern: Is this a valid way of assigning multiple values to an array?

Tags: javascript

I have seen that pattern on CodeReview: 
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/144954/generate-a-table-with-random-numbers

The last function "shuffeledArray".

The following code is used to assign multiple values to an array in one operation:

```js
var demo = [];

[demo[0], demo[1], demo[2]] = [2, 4, 8];

console.log(demo);
```

It works.

But I ask myself:

**Shall one use these technique? Or are there disadvantages?**

Comment: This is introduced in ES6, so older browsers will have compatibility issues. If you are using some tool to convert/minify your code, you can use it, as the tool will take care of it. But on its own, no i will not use it

Comment: I wouldn't use this technique. Imho, it is not only incompatible, but worsens readability. Nobody will punish you, if you assign these three values in three lines with comments. At least, a reader will be able to read this code "on-the-fly".

Comment: That's just a bad example of a useful feature of ES2015. So no, I wouldn't do literally what's above. Yes, I would (and do) use destructuring assignment. (With transpiling for old browsers.)

Comment: Why would you do that instead of `var demo = [2,4,8]`? You *could* also do `var demo = eval('[2,4,8]')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a poor example of a useful feature: Destructuring assignment.

A better example makes the usefulness of destructuring assignment a bit more apparent. Consider the case where a function needs to return more than one return value. Normally, we return an object or an array. With destructuring assignment, we can consume that return value with individual variables:

As an object:

```js
function minMax(a) {
  let min = a[0], max = a[0];
  a.forEach(entry => {
    if (min > entry) {
      min = entry;
    }
    if (max < entry) {
      max = entry;
    }
  });
  return {min, max};
}

let {min, max} = minMax([2, 4, 8]);
console.log(min, max);
```

As an array:

```js
function minMax(a) {
  let min = a[0], max = a[0];
  a.forEach(entry => {
    if (min > entry) {
      min = entry;
    }
    if (max < entry) {
      max = entry;
    }
  });
  return [min, max];
}

let [min, max] = minMax([2, 4, 8]);
console.log(min, max);
```

Destructuring with objects is particularly useful, for instance, when dealing with modules. Suppose a module exports a whole slew of things, of which you need only `foo` and `bar`:

```
import {foo, bar} from "./module";
```

With regard to the browser support argument for not using it: That's what transpiling is for. I've been happily using ES2015 in projects meant for browsers all the way back to IE9 for over two years (yes, before the spec was finalized), thanks to transpiling.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is `ES6` and is perfectly valid, to make it compatible with exsiting browsers, you may need to use babel or tracer to compile your `ES6 code to ES5 code to run in browser.`

```
var [a, b] = [1, 2];
console.log(a, b);
```

The above code is valid of assigning 1 and 2 to a and b respectively.

```
var [a, ...b] = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(a, b);
```

In the above code we are using spread operator assigning `a = 1` and `b = [2,3]`

Loon on more topics on `Array destructing.`

http://www.2ality.com/2015/01/es6-destructuring.html